# Reconnect an external HDD after proper ejection

Tags: usb, external-disk, eject

After I "properly eject" an external HDD or USB stick, can I "reconnect" it without physically unplugging it?

Comment: Does the drive show up in Disk Utility? If so, you can mount it again via there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can!

If you eject the USB HDD by selecting this option:

[image]

Then all you need to do is open **Disk Utility** and check the following:

[image]

Your hard drive will be mounted again!